# node-schedule a cron like scheduling method works in local but not in production

Tags: javascript, node.js, cron

I have to check something after 10 mins of when it is created , I have used node-schdeular it works fine in local but fails in production .
Any ideas.

```
                      jobDate = moment(jobDate).format("MM-DD-YYYY HH:mm:ss");
                        var date = new Date(jobDate);
                        var scheduleDate = moment(date).format("MM-DD-YYYY HH:mm:ss");
                        console.log(scheduleDate);

                        //11-09-2016 18:57:56

                        schedule.scheduleJob(scheduleDate, function () {
                            console.log(booking_id_customer);
                            mBookingModel.findByBookingId(booking_id_customer, function(err, data){

                                if( data.booking_status !='checked_in')
                                {
                                    mBookingModel.findByIdAndUpdate(data._id,{ $set : { booking_status : 'canceled'}}, {new: true }, function(err, doc){
                                      console.log(doc);
                                    });
                                }
                            });
                        })
```

Comment: what do you mean by it fails?

Comment: it doesnot work there

Comment: the function inside schedule is never triggered

Answer (score 0):

Well the server which is running in AWS was set to Virginia and I was trying to run it with Indian timing so the problem occured.